# Why Google Colab displays a list vertically when the number of elements in that list goes beyond a certain value?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I wrote a function that displays the first N prime numbers in Python using Colab. When I print only the first 20 prime numbers, the resulting list is shown horizontally like this:
[image: horizontal]

However, when I print the first 21 prime numbers, the list is in fact displayed vertically that occupies a large space.

Is there a way to enforce Colab to always display lists horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: No, but you can implement your own print function to produce whatever format you like.  The automatic print formatting is just a lazy convenience.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about `Python, not Google Colab (which uses python)`

instead of:

```
print(list)
```

use:

```
print(*list)
```